# Android - Semantic difference between "in app purchase" and Google Wallet digital goods ? (big fee difference)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Does anyone know what the semantic difference is between an in-app purchase in Android, and selling a digital good via Google Wallet?

I can see that there is a big difference in the fee Google charges. In-app purchase fees are 30% of the amount charged. Google Wallet digital goods fees are less than 5%. Obviously, nobody in their right mind wants to pay 25% more than necessary.

I cannot find a text anywhere describing what the difference is as seen with Google's eyes. Does anyone have a link? Or an explanation?

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546371/4224337

Comment: Isn't google wallet just an online payment method like paypal, whereas in app purchases run via android's play store and have nothing to do with the wallet other than being one of the payment options instead of using a credit card?

Comment: I read that Google is actually shutting down in-app purchases via Google Wallet, so Android apps should use Google Play's in-app purchases.